# Append elements of a set to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, set

How do you append the elements of a set to a list in Python in the most succinct way?

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = set([3,4])
>>> a.append(list(b))
>>> a
[1, 2, [3, 4]]
```

But what I want is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use

```
a.extend(list(b))
```

or even easier

```
a.extend(b)
```

instead.

Comment: Spelling error: *extend*, also, it's not necessary to create a list out of the set.

Answer (score 8):

You could use extend as already pointed out, but there's also a more concise approach:

```
>>> a += b
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to update the list, this works for me:

```
a += b
```

If you want a non-mutating expression:

```
a + list(b)
```